# Visual Studio JSON editor - how do I get rid of the schema bar?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

How do I get rid of this annoying pointless bar in the Visual Studio JSON editor?

[image]

Comment: I don't see a setting to remove it.  I am pretty sure there is no way to.

Comment: There is no way to, other than opening the file with another editor (i.e. don't treat it as JSON).  Is there a reason you're trying to remove it other than to reclaim the screen space?

Comment: It's just a distracting waste of space that serves no purpose.